# Negative Lookbehind fails before an Optional Token

Tags: regex, pcre, lookbehind

```
(?<!a)b?c
```

Against `abc`, this regex matches `c`. Am I missing something?

Comment: it treats the input as if it were `bc`, where `b` is "not an `a`" and the optional b is not there

Comment: so it treats b is not there in the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Here is a quick walk-through of the match from the engine's stand point.

- Try to match starting at the position before the `a`. Fail. Advance in the string.
- Try to match starting at the position before the `a`. Fail. Advance in the string.
- Current position: right before the `c`
- Can the negative lookbehind `(?<!a)` assert that what precedes is not `a`? **Check.** (It's `b`)
- Can `b?` match zero or one `b`? **Check.** We match zero `b`
- Can `c` matches a `c`? **Check.**
- Are there any more tokens to match? Nope. We have a match.

**Looking Far Behind**

In .NET, which has infinite lookbehind, you could use this:

```
(?<!a.*)b?c
```

But PCRE does not have infinite lookbehind. You can use this instead:

```
^[^a]*\Kb?c
```

How it works:

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[^a]*` matches any non-a chars
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `b?c` matches the optional `b` and the `c`

Comment: I see, is it possible to declare a regex that consumes the `bc` greedily subsequent to the lookbehind? I thought perhaps, the engine would consume a match and then negate it if a lookbehind disqualifies it. I guess not. Anyway, this can be worked around atleast in my current requirement.

Comment: The lookbehind is evaluated from one particular point in the string. More complex lookbehinds can be built, especiallly in C#. What do you want to do? I'll show you a solution.

Comment: It's okay thanks for your help. I can work around it, I'm not using C#, I'm using haxe which uses pcre. I was trying to match the following: `override public function function_name` match the function name but only when it is not preceded by `override`.

Comment: @MetaChrome for this there are some other workarounds.

Comment: I know: `(?:.(?!override))*(?:public\s)?function (.*?)`

Comment: Thanks for the green checkmark! :) `(?<!a.*)b?c` is one way. If you tell me exactly what you'd like to do, I'll add some options. :)

Comment: Oh that's good and is the logical solution to what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: I see now that you're in PCRE. I thought you were in .NET. The small regex I gave you won't work in PCRE because it doesn't have infinite lookbehind. In PCRE I would use this: `^[^a]*\Kb?c`

Comment: FYI added explanation for the PCRE regex `^[^a]*\Kb?c`

Comment: PS, `^` does not negate a match against a particular string rather a character set, which isn't applicable. I am currently doing: `/^(?!override)(?:.(?!override))*function init_([\w]*)/`

Answer (score 1):

Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called **"lookaround"**, are **zero-length assertions** just like the start and end of line, and start and end of word anchors.

> They `do not consume characters in the string`, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

For more info See [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Hey @braj, I think he knows that, to me his problem has nothing to do with consuming characters. His problem is why `(?<!a)` doesn't seem to be working in `abc`... If you stand before the `b`, you're thinking "wait, `(?<!a)` should fail, since there's an `a`... So why am I matching a `c`?"